# Alternative to React refs in event handler?

Tags: reagent

I've asked this question on github and google groups. Got not result. So the question is:

Suppose I want to create some reusable components.

```
(defn song-player []
  "display songs and controls"
  (let [current-song (atom {"title" "some title", "url" "some-url"})]
    (fn []
      [:div.player
       [:p "title: " (@current-song "title")]
       [:audio#player-audio
        {:src (str (@current-song "url"))}]
       [:input {:type "button"
                :value "Play/Stop"
                :on-click #(let [player (. js/document (getElementById "player-audio"))]
                             (if (.-paused player)
                               (.play player)
                               (.pause player)))}]])))
```

Suppose I will want several song-player in one page. In that case I cannot assign ID(#player-audio) to the audio element, because the page will have duplicate ID.

So how do I refer to local component in event handler? In this case, how do I refer to the local audio element in the event handler of on-click event?

In react.js, I can assign a ref to the audio component and refer to by this.refs.XXX. How do I do this in reagent? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a few issues with how your trying to do this. In particular, the
way you are using the atom and your use of getElementById, which is likely to cause
problems with reagent/react. My suggestion would be to use the atom to keep all the
state (including the state of the audio player).

If we assume that title is unique and can be used as a key, I would store all the
players as a hash of hashes. It would probably be useful to create a function which
takes a song title as an argument and returns a keyword representation i.e.

```
(keyword-title "Some Title") => :some-title

{:first-title {:title "First Title"
               :url "http://....."
       :player :stop} ;; could be :stop :pause :play etc
 :another-title {:title "Another Title"
                 :url "some other url"
         :player :stop}}
```

When you create a 'new' player component, what your actually doing is adding another
entry to the state atom. When you want interactive buttons/components, you define
them to operate on the state atom. Then you define a component which just renders all
the entries from your state atom.

```
(defn song-player [title url player-state]
  (let [players (r/atom {})] ;; this will only be called once - first time
    (fn [title url player-state]
  (swap! players assoc (keyword-title title) {:title title
                                              :url url
                          :player player-state})
  [player-component players])))
```

The first time you call song-player, it will create the players atom and then it will
call the anonymous function. This anonymous function is now the render function for
this component. This is why it is important that the anonymous function and the
parent function have the same parameter signatures.

The player-component takes the players atom, which contains all the state info about
the titles and state of the player associated with each title, walks through the atom
and renders each entry accrodingly

```
(defn player-component [players]
  (into [:div]
        (for [p (keys @players)]
     ^{:key p} [:div.player
                 [:p "Title: " (get-in @players [p :title])]
         [:audio {:src (get-in @players [p :url])}]
         [:input {:type "button"
                  :value (get-in @players [p :player-state])
              :on-click #(toggle-player-state p players)}]])))
```

the toggle-player-state sets whatever the new state is when someone clicks the button

```
(defn toggle-player-state [player-id players]
  (if (= :stop (get-in @players [player-id :player-state]))
    (swap! players assoc-in [player-id :player-state] :play)
(swap! players assoc-in [player-id :player-state] :stop)))
```

Obviously, this is just off the top of my head, has not been tested and is really
more pseudo code than anything else. I don't know what the [:audio] type expands to
and there could be limitations with it which need to be catered for or other event
handlers you will need to setup (such as :on-complete or whatever). However, the
principal should be about right. With Reagent/react, I think the goal is to avoid
setting/reading the DOM directly. You manage the state and let reagent/react do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know anything about anything, but I've been searching for the answer to something similar, and what I've come up with so far is:

1. Reagent doesn't store refs (which you could theoretically find using
   "this-as this" inside your function) but
2. You can jimmy your way into one using the method shown in the component-did-mount callback here: https://gist.github.com/danielytics/d4374cd51deec7201250

I'm sure this is much too late to help you, but you never know.